# how to add stacklabel total on Highcharts columnrange?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I'm currently working with Highcharts columnrange and I need to add stack label on top of each column/each month in order to show Total Number of Hours our Store is being Opened.. But sadly, I've tried different ways and still no joy.

Here's the current jsfiddle that I have;
http://jsfiddle.net/rds_a/0mLa0yd5/2/

Here's the code;

```
 $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        data: {
            table: 'summary'
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'columnrange'
        },
        colors: ['black', 'orange'],
        title: {
            text: 'Jackstone Store'
        },


        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            title: {
                text: 'Units'
            },
                stackLabels: {
          enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            columnrange: {
                grouping: false,

                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Something like that master, but what I need is Total on top of each column/ each day. I will send you a better jsfiddle.

Comment: Editted my jsfiddle for much clearer version of my chart.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show data labels on top in stacked column graph in highcharts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300184/show-data-labels-on-top-in-stacked-column-graph-in-highcharts)

Comment: But there's not such thing like "stackLabels" for columnrange. Imho, stacking for column-range doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Hi Pawel Fus, is there any way on how to put total on columnrange? Somehow it doesn't sounds good but the Total where our store is opened means a lot to us :( Can you help me to this do this?

Comment: Is there any reason not to just use a stacked column here instead?

Comment: I need to use columnrange on this project, we want to show the time range where the store is being opened.

Comment: So in that case you need to iterate on each serie / point, compare x values to find points "in the same place". Then use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) to add text with sum of "stack"